# Javascript - Variable inside "style.width ="

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("rec-icono-li");    
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.width = (div_width * 0.2) + "px";
}
```

I've set the `div_width` variable and it does return a numeric value. In fact I'm using this variable elsewhere. The problem is in the code I've posted above, obviously, because if I change the final line to `x[i].style.width = "100px";` it works fine.

Comment: form where div_width is comming?

Comment: Where is div_width defined? Show your code.

Comment: try this `((Number)div_width * 0.2)`

Comment: Can you console the value of the `div_width` inside the loop if there is actually a value or what was its value?

Comment: @Khaleel: Not an issue in this case - it will be treated as a number. Just checked.

Comment: set a breakpoint on your code.. usually with things like this div_width is being given a string value. My guess is div_width is being set to "100px" somewhere along the way(not necessarily initially but are you updating it?), so `(div_width * 0.2) + "px"` becomes "NaNpx"

Answer (score 0):

you could use [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) method:

to obtain 100px your `div_width` should be `500`.

let's try this source code:

```
// here the value of div_width
    div_width = 500;
// here the value of div_width

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("rec-icono-li");    
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.width = (parseFloat(div_width) * 0.2) + "px";
}
```